# how to publish my first app in play-store

Tags: google-play, publish

Good days 
Please excuse me  i want to ask you how to publish my app in playstore for make it downloadable by many people

Please it is my first expérience with publishing mobile app 
Thank for all your responses.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. This site is geared towards answering questions concerning programming languages. You might find better luck asking at [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thank i am asking in that section.

Comment: Thank you for your help !
Please Mr Idan Adar Help me i 'don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to create:

1.Log In to https://play.google.com/console (click, Go to play Console)

2. Create a developer account (pay $25 DEVELOPER FEE)
3. Fill out the registration form
4. Click on "create app "
   5.(Other steps you can see Yt tutorial)

yt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GHT4QtotE4

I refer that the **yt** tutorial is not mine.

BYE HAVE A GREAT DAY